# Can you add platform specific code in PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova

If I have an application build using PhoneGap is it possible to add to it platform specific code?

For instance, for an iOS version I would like to add [Heatma.ps SDK](https://heatma.ps).
Heatma.ps SDK is an iOS specific static library written in Objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add as much platform specific code as you want. Phonegap is just for the interaction of the platform specific code and the javascript. Its the plugin mechanism that makes Phonegap what it is.
 Even if you have a native app, you can add a bit of Phonegap in it by having a page somewhere which is basically a webview and is manipulated by js. Phonegap is what launches and manages the interactions of the js and the native part of the app.